# Does Cyttorak know about Colossus?

Tags: marvel, x-men, colossus, juggernaut

Is Cyttorak (the 'diety' who gives power to the Juggernaut via a gem) aware that Colossus has usurped the Juggernaut's power?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since it happened in front of him.

Colossus took on the power of Juggernaut in *Uncanny X-Men* #542. [Colossus' entry](https://marvel.fandom.com/Piotr_Rasputin_%28Earth-616%29#Fear_Itself) on the Marvel Wiki states:

> When Kuurth attacked San Francisco, the X-Men failed to stop him. Magik used her powers to teleport herself, Colossus and Kitty Pryde into the Crimson Cosmos and meet with [Cyttorak]. Illyana told Cyttorak that Cain Marko betrayed him and now served to another god. [Cyttorak] took his power back from Marko and Magik intended to become his new avatar, but [Colossus] intercepted, becoming the new Juggernaut, much to the displeasure of Kitty Pryde.

Here are the pages in question, where it all unfolds in the presence of Cyttorak:

[image: Cyttorak looming over the three X-Men in Uncanny X-Men #542]

And later:

[image: Colossus accepting the power from Cyttorak in Uncanny X-Men #542]